# Adding rows from db to a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexoutofboundsexception

Error :

> index out of rangeMust be non negative and les than size of collection parameter name index

Code :

```
try
 {
     int i = 0;
     Query = "select * from customeritems where cid = '" + GlobalVars.id + "';";
     cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Query, GlobalVars.conn);
     dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     if ((dr != null) && (dr.HasRows))
     {
                    dgvItems.Rows.Clear();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        dgvItems.Rows.Add();
                        dgvItems.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        dgvItems.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = (i + 1).ToString();
                        dgvItems.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        dgvItems.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                        dgvItems.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
                        dgvItems.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = dr.GetValue(5).ToString();
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
   }
```

I set break point on i++. At this point it gives the above mentioned error. Any ideas?

P.S. I get the first record fine

Comment: c# ..................................

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: well i set breakpoint on every line in while loop. the loop runs fine once till i++. at this point i press F5 it give error "index out of range etc."

Comment: I can see that you get values from database using GetValue(0) for example but you are missing GetValue(1) because second column is row index. So maybe you should have index shifted and last column from database is 4 not 5? dr.GetValue(4)? Basically i mean that maybe you have 5 columns in your query result not 6?

Comment: VS already stops the execution when an exception is thrown, you don't have set breakpoints on each line.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Checked that already mate.

Comment: @user2982914 where is the `dr.GetValue(1)`?

Comment: IMO - the most obvious candidate would be the Cells[x] or Rows[i] as I see it. Where do you have the definition of dgvItems and it's rows?

Comment: try Checking dgView.Rows[i].Cells.Count > 5 and dr.FieldCount > 5 as true before going forward with adding the values.

Comment: How can you add rows to a datagridview without adding columns first? Also, your objects dr and cmd don't have types. How is that? Lastly why don't you simply bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you are either violating a PK constraint or a null value constraint in dgvItems. That's usually the root of the problem when one insert works, then the next one fails. Also, it looks like you're going to have a problem if `i` gets any bigger than 5.